# I can;t get the gnupg decryption method from the gnupg library to work

Tags: python, gnupg

I have some code that looks like this:

```
    import gnupg                                                                    
                                                                                  
    encrypted_file = "/<path_to_file>/key.txt.gpg"              
    gpg_passphrase = "<my passphrase>"                                              
    gpg = gnupg.GPG()                                                               
                                                                                  
    f = open(encrypted_file,"rb")                                                   
                                                                                  
    data = f.read()                                                                 
                                                                                  
    decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(str(data),passphrase = 
                                 gpg_passphrase)                
    print ("decrypted_data  = ", decrypted_data.data)
```

When I decrypt the data manually in the linux shell using gpg -o -d  it works fine.  This tells me that the passphrase is correct.  I cannot, however, get this to work from Python. I tried an alternative approach using the decrypt_file method to create a decrypted file which I could then read, but the method doesn't produce anything either.

I should have said that I am getting this output from the print statement.

```
decrypted_data    b''
```

Anybody see what I'm missing here?

Thanks